# Used chmod on chmod 777 /home in an aws ubuntu server and now every ubuntu server can't login

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I first got this error when i ran chmod 777 /home. I lost the means to reconnect to the server. After i closed the server i trying launching a fresh instance and still couldn't connect to it.

Comment: Have you tried with SSM Session manager? May need to add `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy to its role if not already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably down to you updating the permissions of of users `.ssh` folder.

Ensure that each users `.ssh` folder is `chmod 600` with the `authorized_keys` also `chmod 600`. All other files in the `.ssh` folder should be `chmod 400`.

If you're able to connect via session manager you should be able to change these permissions. Otherwise you would need to attach the volume to a different EC2 as a secondary volume and change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to connect to your instance using the following methods and then try to fix the permission issue:

- [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#start-ec2-console) as the "ssm-user"
- [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console) as the root user (browser-based SSH connection)

On the other hand, you could add a new user account with appropriate ownership and file permissions for the SSH directory and the files in it using cloud-init and user data, please see [this article.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-user-account-cloud-init-user-data/)